# autoit script Sr, can i help me

Tags: actionscript-3, autoit

i have a problem
i write a autoit script for a website. this web have button when i click this button , a other website is created (popup)
my goal is i want to get url popup website
when i inspect element that button , it display as:

(https://www.facebook.com/pages/H%E1%BA%A2I-S%E1%BA%A2N-T%C6%AF%C6%A0I-S%E1%BB%90NG/838221676190845?ref=hl,Facebook,5,1');" class="followbutton">Like)

can you get url :https://www.facebook.com/pages/H%E1%BA%A2I-S%E1%BA%A2N-T%C6%AF%C6%A0I-S%E1%BB%90NG/838221676190845?ref=hl

then store it in a variable example $oIE

can i help me this , thanks.
sr because of my english, i am vietnamese.
thanks all.

Comment: Did you mean to flag this as Actionscript 3? Are you using Flash?

Comment: If that's the link you want as variable and it won't change then why dont you just paste that URL into your code? I don't know how you're programming but the logic is `variable $oIE = "https://www.facebo..."`...(with full link pasted in there)

Comment: it is a variable, when link url at in button, when i click button, a tab will be appear (popup)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding. You've got a button, which you want to open this URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use [IEAttach](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEAttach.htm) to get an object of already created IE instances.

```
; *******************************************************
; Example 1 - Attach to a browser with "HẢI SẢN TƯƠI SỐNG" in its title, display the URL
; *******************************************************

#include <IE.au3>

Local $oIE2 = _IEAttach("HẢI SẢN TƯƠI SỐNG")
MsgBox(0, "The URL", _IEPropertyGet($oIE2, "locationurl"))
```